# How to return custom error from API Gateway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud

I have a Lambda application integrated with API Gateway, and I want to return this response body in the case of 409 error (conflict exception)

```
{
  "message": "some error message",
  "someObject": {
    "propert1": "val1"
  }
}
```

But according to this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Response.html#error-property, the error object doesn't expose deserialized data from service, except for `message`. Hence, in my JavaScript application, I only have an access to `message` property: "some error message", but I need to access `someObject`. How can I solve this? Do I need to serialize the object and bind it to message property?

I am using REST API and in Lambda we use javax.ws.rs.core.Response to return a response

```
data class Error(val message: String, val someObject: SomeDataClass)
...
val error = Error('message', someObject)
return Response.status(code).entity(error).build()
```

Comment: That document you are linking to is the response for the Javascript SDK not the response of your API Gateway.

Your Lambda and API gateway will dictate the response body. If you can show some of your Lambda code (what it returns) and your API Gateway configuration, that will help us understand it better.

Comment: Edited the description

Comment: You might want to override the response using the mapping template of API gateway. The idea would be send the response as you are doing now and write some velocity template to create your desired response. You would be able to extract the object data into JSON in mapping template and poplate that information into response.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html